# Kinect Speech not getting Recognizer

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect, speech

I don't know how many of you have experience with the Kinect, but I posted this over on MSDN forums nearly two weeks ago and got no help.I've been racking my brain trying to get this to work maybe someone here can help.I am trying to add speech to my application that uses gestures normally.I'm using the KinectSensorChooser and straight after the skeletonStream is enabled I start the sensor then I try to start the voice recognition.
I'm using the turtle example, which works fine so everything is installed properly.I've tracked the code and came to know that the RecognizerInfo isn't being found.Note the "test" messagebox doesn't show:

**Code**:

```
private static RecognizerInfo GetKinectRecognizer()
    {

        foreach (RecognizerInfo recognizer in SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers())
        {MessageBox.Show("test");
            string value;
            recognizer.AdditionalInfo.TryGetValue("Kinect", out value);
            if ("True".Equals(value, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && "en-US".Equals(recognizer.Culture.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {

                return recognizer;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Any ideas why? Been stuck on this half the day and can't find a solution.Note that there's a bug in which the audiostream stops if the skeleton stream starts after it. so I changed the order they start and no difference.I'm using SDK 1.6 and x86 install of the speech package. No errors or exceptions. [The original post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdkaudioapi/thread/edaf0862-a589-436a-abcc-48af2edb5745) is here. Can anybody shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1):

i was having the very same problem, i found this post and i decided to answer now that i could solve the issue.

After 4 days of dealing with this, uninstalling and installing everything i was told by a microsoft student partner that i should install eveything in a specific order.

1st: uninstall everything, kinect sdk, driver, runtime, etc.
2: install kinect sdk.
3: install microsoft speech
4: install the language packs you need.

I am using kinect sdk 1.5 and this worked for me.

it seems microsoft it is not compatible with itself LOL. 
Regards!
Caro